# Importing a fixed module from a dynamic path at runtime in python3

Tags: python, dynamic, import

I have searched around and not found a solution to this particular Python3 problem. Perhaps it's the keywords I'm using, or it could be just a special use case. In the event that my problem is the latter, here is my question:

I'm developing a python (3) script which needs to use a python module which has been compiled locally in the user's home directory. I do not have anything so fancy as a configure script to configure this path for the user as an automated process. I want to pass the path to the python module to the script at runtime as a command line argument, and then dynamically load that module. For example, I will call:

```
$ myscript.py --modpath /home/user/path/to/ModuleSource
```

and then in my code call something like the following when I parse the command line arguments:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(localModulePath)
import GlobalModuleName
```

The problem is that in the static code for my script which uses the module methods, the actual module cannot be resolved until runtime when the definitions for the module are passed to my script.
That is, if I have python code like the following

```
GlobalModuleName.moduleFunc()
```

I get runtime errors of "*NameError: name 'GlobalModuleName' is not defined*".

How do I get this configuration to work without generating an error? I am certain that the code that will use the dynamic definitions of the module is correct. Thanks for the pointers in advance.

Comment: I realize completely that this is not the most optimal way to do this. My superviser is extremely finicky about the requirement that the script not require ``sudo`` access to configure / install the global module sources. The end point of this is that the target users will be running the script on machines where we absolutely do not have rights to set any paths. It might be possible to set an environment variable to include this path to the global module source, but I would much prefer a hackish solution where my description and use case works correctly just by knowing the module source paths.

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/31/advanced-python-how-to-dynamically-load-modules-or-classes/) about dynamic module or class loading could help you.

Comment: @Lukas I actually saw that article when I searched before posting. The solutions do not seem to work for me. I am able to test that the module works after I update the path with ``sys.path``. The problem is (seems to be) that I need this module in prerequisite source files which are imported before I call the ``argparser`` to find the dynamic location of the module sources. Can you suggest some sample code to show me where I'm getting the link's suggestions wrong?

Comment: That is, I cannot load the module until after parsing the command line arguments. The source files that are loaded at the top of my ``main`` script need this module. Python seems to insist on parsing all of the included source code (including the failed dependencies on the module) before I am able to resolve the module source path at runtime. (*sigh*)

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me

**module1.py**
    import os
    import sys

```
def func1():
    print("Executed func1 of module1")
```

**main.py**

```
import sys

pathPassed=sys.argv[1]
sys.path.append(pathPassed)
import module1
module1.func1()
```

**Execution**

```
 python main.py ThePathformodule1.py

Executed func1 of module1
```

The only thing you have to take care is that the `import` statement should be after the `sys.path.append`